# Bottlenecking: GTX 970 & AMD FX-6300

Tags: gaming, graphics-cards, processor

Alright, I am looking for a fairly priced CPU that will not hold back the ASUS STRIX GTX 970 very little or not at all. Preferably Intel, as their processor lineup shows to last longer for generations in gaming. Also hoping to use this for Fallout 4. 
Thank you!

Comment: anything above (and including) i5 2300 will not bottleneck the gtx 970. There's one thing that's frequently mis interpreted: Cpu bottleneck happens to mid to low end and 2-3years old. if you've a fairly high end cpu like an i5 2300 or above you're good to go with mono gpu's. The only place where cpu might be relative would be in cpu heavy games (civilisation V). any recent game like the witcher 3 will not load the cpu but the gpu.

Comment: The GPU technology is really behind the rest in computing. high end gpu (gtx 980ti) don't even use a x16 pci express 2.0 port to it's full capacity. last year's high end cards (780 or more) lost only 5% on a x16 pci exp 1.1 port.
For gaming just get a high end i5 and you're good for 4-5years  without getting a cpu bottleneck.
so i'd recommend a i5 4670 or above just in case you're doing some cpu heavy stuff on your time off gaming.

Comment: This is not a hardware recommendation. What you are asking for is what would happen if CPU+GPU were put together.

Comment: I'm using athlon 750k on ultra and only occasionally have drops to 30-40 FPS in Fallout 4. FX-6300 puts out almost twice the performance of 750k according to geekbench 3, it should be fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The minimum requrment for Fallout 4 is a i5-2300 and the recommended is a i7-4970k. The current recomendation on PC Building Communities is to go with either the i5-4690k or the i5-6600k. These two are almost equal in gaming performance, but the 6600K is newer and runs on a new socket and technology.

The best recommendation is a 6600K on the Z170 platform for overclocking. Just be sure to get a CPU Cooler as the 6600K doesn't include one. Also be sure to get DDR4 Ram.

If you are upgrading and already have a LGA1150 Processor, just go with the i5-4690K on the Z97 Platform, which uses DDR3.

Comment: and these will both work really well with this GPU?

Comment: @SBlas Yes. I do have one thing to say though... Have you considered the R9 390? It has better performance the the GTX 970, no VRAM issues, and is the same price.

Comment: looking into it

Comment: I'd recommend getting a dx 12 oriented  gpu and a an i5 above 4440.
dx12 which will be the new standard in the upcoming games reduces the cpu load by a lot. so truthfull even an i5 2300 will not bottleneck on a dx12 game and fallout 4 will run just fine ;)